# How can I use regular expression for unicode string in python?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-2.x

Hi I wanna use regular expression for unicode utf-8 in following string:

```
</td><td>عـــــــــــادي</td><td> 40.00</td>
```

I want to pick `"عـــــــــــادي"` out, how Can I do this?

My code for this is :

```
state = re.findall(r'td>...</td',s)
```

Thanks

Comment: Note that Python’s standard `re` module doesn’t work very well on Unicode. It doesn’t do casefolding, doesn’t support the mandatory Unicode properties, etc etc. Instead you should get Matthew Barnett’s awesome `regex` module, which works both in Python2 and Python3. It’s really cool, and super powerful.

Answer (score 6):

I ran across something similar when trying to match a string in Russian. For your situation, Michele's answer works fine. If you want to use special sequences like `\w` and `\s`, though, you have to change some things. I'm just sharing this, hoping it will be useful to someone else.

```
>>> string = u"</td><td>Я люблю мороженое</td><td> 40.00</td>"
```

Make your string unicode by placing a `u` before the quotation marks

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(ur'>([\w\s]+)<', re.UNICODE)
```

Set the flag to unicode, so that it will match unicode strings as well (see [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#compilation-flags)).

(Alternatively, you can use your local language to set a range. For Russian this would be `[а-яА-Я]`, so:

```
pattern = re.compile(ur'>([а-яА-Я\s]+)<')
```

In that case, you don't have to set a flag anymore, since you're not using a special sequence.)

```
>>> match = pattern.findall(string)
>>> for i in match:
...     print i
... 
Я люблю мороженое
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [PEP 0264: Defining Python Source Code Encodings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), first you need to tell Python the whole source file is UTF-8 encoded by adding a comment like this to the first line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Furthermore, try adding '*ur*' before the string so that it's **raw** *and* **Unicode**:

```
state = re.search(ur'td>([^<]+)</td',s)
res = state.group(1)
```

I've also edited your regex to make it match. Three dots mean "exactly three characters", but since you are using UTF-8, which is a multi-byte encoding, this may not work as expected.

Comment: I suggest changing that line to `state = re.search(ur'td>([^<]+)</td',s)` and then getting the desired output by calling `state.group(1)`.